# Where is the best place to put a local repo?

Tags: debian, directory-structure, repository

I've made a custom repo to install ruby 2.0 on Ubuntu 12.04

Currently, I have the repo in '/vagrant/files' for testing.

```
root@gitlab:~# tree /vagrant/files/
/vagrant/files/
|-- default
|-- ruby2-repo
|   |-- libruby2.0_2.0.0.299-2_amd64.deb
|   |-- Packages.gz
|   |-- rake_10.0.4-1_all.deb
|   |-- ruby2.0_2.0.0.299-2_amd64.deb
|   |-- ruby2.0-dev_2.0.0.299-2_amd64.deb
|   `-- rubygems-integration_1.2_all.deb

root@gitlab:~# cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ruby2-0.list
deb file:///vagrant/files/ruby2-repo /
```

I'm thinking I'll just put the ruby2-0.list directory in home or /opt.

Is there a best practice or standard for where to store local repos?

Comment: Relevant: http://people.connexer.com/~roberto/howtos/debrepository

Comment: That is one of the links I used in researching how to create a debian repo. The examples use generic locations like: file:///path/to/repository/

Comment: It also suggests the following paths (see the setting up section): `~/packages/`,`/packages/`,`/var/www/debian/`, `/usr/local/packages/` which to me implies there is no default path.

Comment: Imho I normally put custom repos in /var/www/html so I can easily access them with other machines. If you only have the one computer accessing the repo it shouldn't matter much.